# HOw to compress files in the shopify to improve web speed

Tags: compression, shopify, google-pagespeed

My website is on shopify platform. Google test show following message

Compressing resources with gzip or deflate can reduce the number of bytes sent over the network.

Enable compression for the following resources to reduce their transfer size by 1.6MiB (78% reduction).

Compressing https://sdk.azureedge.net/js/1.b... could save 1.6MiB (78% reduction).

How can I compress these files in shopify?

Answer (score 4):

You can speed up your Google Speed test by compressing your websites (.js) file

Google itself provides its Closure Compiler for this purpose.

refer  [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/)

**P.S.** Take backup of your JS file before updating in your store js because its compressed code cannot be rolled back to its original state after being compiled.

Comment: If you find this answer satisfying please approve the answer so that it becomes useful for other users finding solutions of such problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Shopify, most likely those PageSpeed warnings are coming from 3rd party apps.

In that case you can just reach out to them and ask if they will compress the file.

If you don't know which app it is, you can go to the domain name or try searching "what is *[paste file path here]*".

For Shopify specifically, you can get more details and a template [from this post](https://speedboostr.com/enable-compression-on-shopify/).